# Holding Shift While Clicking?

Tags: c#, api, mouse

i was wondering wether it is possible to hold down shift while clicking with the mouse.

It would look simmilar to this: - If you could simulate a mouse click with the SendKeys.SendWait function - `SendKeys.SendWait(+{Mouseclick});`
So far I have called the API "User32.dll" to call the mouse click:

```
public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x2;
public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x4;
public const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x20;
public const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x40;
public const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x8;
public const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButton, int dwExtra);

 mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

However; is it possible to hold the Shift key down at the same time?

Regards, DotTutorials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`keybd_event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to simulate the Shift key.  Something like:

```
public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x2;
public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x4;
public const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x20;
public const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x40;
public const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x8;
public const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;
public const byte KEYBDEVENTF_SHIFTVIRTUAL = 0x10;
public const byte KEYBDEVENTF_SHIFTSCANCODE = 0x2A;
public const int KEYBDEVENTF_KEYDOWN = 0;
public const int KEYBDEVENTF_KEYUP = 2;
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButton, int dwExtra);
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="keybd_event", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling=true)]
public static extern void keybd_event(byte vk, byte scan, int flags, int extrainfo);

// shift down
keybd_event(KEYBDEVENTF_SHIFTVIRTUAL, KEYBDEVENTF_SHIFTSCANCODE, KEYBDEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
// shift up
keybd_event(KEYBDEVENTF_SHIFTVIRTUAL, KEYBDEVENTF_SHIFTSCANCODE, KEYBDEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks man, you did not have to put so much effort into the answer, but  thanks big time!

Comment: Thanks this really helped me, one question.. where do you find the keycodes I cant seem to do the right query in google.